# My redirect_url page requires a csrf_token

Tags: payment-gateway, flutterwave

is there a way to walk around laravel csrf token because your api can't post to my redirect_url, do I have to append anything to the calling parameter or something, because I think that csrf is actually important.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add ur `url path` to the csrf exception in your laravel.